# (Update) Add index column to data.frame based on two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, addition, col

Example data.frame:

```
df = read.table(text = 'colA colB
                2 7
                2 7
                2 7
                2 7
                1 7
                1 7
                1 7
                89 5
                89 5
                89 5
                88 5
                88 5
                70 5
                70 5
                70 5
                69 5
                69 5
                44 4
                44 4
                44 4
                43 4
                42 4
                42 4
                41 4
                41 4
                120 1
                100 1', header = TRUE)
```

I need to add an index col based on `colA` and `colB` where `colB` shows the exact number of rows to group but it can be duplicated. `colB` groups rows based on `colA` and `colA -1`.

Expected output:

```
 colA colB index_col
    2 7       1
    2 7       1
    2 7       1
    2 7       1
    1 7       1
    1 7       1
    1 7       1
    89 5      2
    89 5      2
    89 5      2
    88 5      2
    88 5      2
    70 5      3
    70 5      3
    70 5      3
    69 5      3
    69 5      3
    44 4      4
    44 4      4 
    44 4      4
    43 4      4
    42 4      5
    42 4      5
    41 4      5
    41 4      5
   120 1      6
   100 1      7
```

---

UPDATE

How can I adapt the code that works for the above `df` for the same purpose but by looking at `colB` values grouped based on `colA`, `colA -1` and `colA -2`? i.e. (instead of 2 days considering 3 days)

```
new_df = read.table(text = 'colA colB
        3 10
        3 10
        3 10      
        2 10
        2 10
        2 10
        2 10
        1 10
        1 10
        1 10
        90 7
        90 7
        89 7
        89 7
        89 7
        88 7
        88 7
        71 7
        71 7
        70 7
        70 7
        70 7
        69 7
        69 7
        44 5
        44 5
        44 5
        43 5
        42 5
        41 5
        41 5
        41 5
        40 5
        40 5
       120 1
       100 1', header = TRUE)
```

Expected output:

```
     colA colB index_col
        3 10      1
        3 10      1
        3 10      1
        2 10      1
        2 10      1
        2 10      1
        2 10      1
        1 10      1
        1 10      1
        1 10      1
        90 7      2
        90 7      2
        89 7      2
        89 7      2
        89 7      2
        88 7      2
        88 7      2
        71 7      3
        71 7      3
        70 7      3
        70 7      3
        70 7      3
        69 7      3
        69 7      3
        44 5      4
        44 5      4
        44 5      4
        43 5      4
        42 5      4
        41 5      5
        41 5      5
        41 5      5
        40 5      5
        40 5      5
       120 1      6
       100 1      7
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what is `index_col`. Does it increment after two groups of `colA`?

Comment: question updated

Comment: index_col increments each time it finds a new colB value but I need to distinguish between duplicated colB values, as colB group colA based on colA and colA -1

Comment: Why does index_col increment between colA=69 and colA=89?

Comment: in total there are 5 groups in df that need to be grouped (indexed): colA = 2 and 1, colA = 70 and 69, colA = 89 and 88, colA = 120 and colA = 100

Comment: so, the value of `colB` decides how many times the `index_col` is repeated, right?

Comment: Seems the counter is just base on colB? If so, very convuluted way !! `with(rle(df$colB), { n = (lengths / values) ; rep(seq(sum(n)), rep(values, n)) })`

Comment: @Aramis7d yes! but it can be duplicated because of the grouping characteristic (ie colA + colA -1)

Comment: @user2957945 is not right

Comment: @aaaaa ; fair enough, but any more info as to why its not right as it matches your outcome

Comment: @aaaaa  The comment is not clear.  Could you update your post with the expected output

Comment: What is wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
index_col <-setDT(df)[, if(colB[1L] < .N) ((seq_len(.N)-1) %/% colB[1L])+1  
       else as.numeric(colB), rleid(colB)][, rleid(V1)]
df[, index_col := index_col]
df
#    colA colB index_col
# 1:    2    7         1
# 2:    2    7         1
# 3:    2    7         1
# 4:    2    7         1
# 5:    1    7         1
# 6:    1    7         1
# 7:    1    7         1
# 8:   70    5         2
# 9:   70    5         2
#10:   70    5         2
#11:   69    5         2
#12:   69    5         2
#13:   89    5         3
#14:   89    5         3
#15:   89    5         3
#16:   88    5         3
#17:   88    5         3
#18:  120    1         4
#19:  100    1         5
```

---

Or a one-liner would be

```
setDT(df)[, index_col := df[, ((seq_len(.N)-1) %/% colB[1L])+1, rleid(colB)][, as.integer(interaction(.SD, drop = TRUE, lex.order = TRUE))]]
```

#### Update

Based on the new update in the OP's post

```
setDT(new_df)[, index_col :=  cumsum(c(TRUE, abs(diff(colA))> 1))
          ][, colB := .N , index_col]
new_df
#    colA colB index_col
# 1:    3   10         1
# 2:    3   10         1
# 3:    3   10         1
# 4:    2   10         1
# 5:    2   10         1
# 6:    2   10         1
# 7:    2   10         1
# 8:    1   10         1
# 9:    1   10         1
#10:    1   10         1
#11:   71    7         2
#12:   71    7         2
#13:   70    7         2
#14:   70    7         2
#15:   70    7         2
#16:   69    7         2
#17:   69    7         2
#18:   90    7         3
#19:   90    7         3
#20:   89    7         3
#21:   89    7         3
#22:   89    7         3
#23:   88    7         3
#24:   88    7         3
#25:   44    2         4
#26:   43    2         4
#27:  120    1         5
#28:  100    1         6
```

Comment: thank you. what about if I need to group colB observations with a time window of n days? e.g. instead of colA and colA -1 I want to group them by colA, colA -1 and colA -2. (with the above input data.frame the output will not change)

Comment: @aaaaa  I think this info was not in your original post

Comment: no is not and I will mark my answer based on what I asked. but how can I adapt your code to different time windows? thanks

Comment: @aaaaa  That is fine.  What I meant is that it is not clear from your description about the grouping

Comment: new question similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44341762/add-new-rank-column-to-data-frame-based-on-rows-grouped-by-episodes-of-specific

Answer (score 1):

An approach in base R:

```
df$idxcol <- cumsum(c(1,abs(diff(df$colA)) > 1) + c(0,diff(df$colB) != 0) > 0)
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df
>    colA colB idxcol
> 1     2    7      1
> 2     2    7      1
> 3     2    7      1
> 4     2    7      1
> 5     1    7      1
> 6     1    7      1
> 7     1    7      1
> 8    70    5      2
> 9    70    5      2
> 10   70    5      2
> 11   69    5      2
> 12   69    5      2
> 13   89    5      3
> 14   89    5      3
> 15   89    5      3
> 16   88    5      3
> 17   88    5      3
> 18  120    1      4
> 19  100    1      5
> ```

---

On the updated example data, you need to adapt the approach to:

```
n <- 1
idx1 <- cumsum(c(1, diff(df$colA) < -n) + c(0, diff(df$colB) != 0) > 0)
idx2 <- ave(df$colA, cumsum(c(1, diff(df$colA) < -n)), FUN = function(x) c(0, cumsum(diff(x)) < -n ))
idx2[idx2==1 & c(0,diff(idx2))==0] <- 0

df$idxcol <- idx1 + cumsum(idx2)
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df
>    colA colB idxcol
> 1     2    7      1
> 2     2    7      1
> 3     2    7      1
> 4     2    7      1
> 5     1    7      1
> 6     1    7      1
> 7     1    7      1
> 8    89    5      2
> 9    89    5      2
> 10   89    5      2
> 11   88    5      2
> 12   88    5      2
> 13   70    5      3
> 14   70    5      3
> 15   70    5      3
> 16   69    5      3
> 17   69    5      3
> 18   44    4      4
> 19   44    4      4
> 20   44    4      4
> 21   43    4      4
> 22   42    4      5
> 23   42    4      5
> 24   41    4      5
> 25   41    4      5
> 26  120    1      6
> 27  100    1      7
> ```

For `new_df` just change `n` tot `2` and you will get the desired output for that as well.

Comment: thank you. what about if I need to group colB observations with a time window of n days? e.g. instead of colA and colA -1 I want to group them by colA, colA -1 and colA -2. (with the above input data.frame the output will not change)

Comment: thank you both. I chose you because the code is more simple to understand and it can be applied for different data.frames.

Comment: I have got a similar question (a bit more complex) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44250468/create-index-column-based-on-existent-groups-of-rows-with-duplicates

Comment: Hi, I just spotted that  your code does not work 100% with my real data.frame. I updated my example data.frames (df and new_df) could you please have a look? please..thanks

Comment: will your update works with any window length or only with colA, colA -1 and colA -2? thanks

Comment: @aaaaa see the added line at the end of the anser; does that help?