# Create index column based on existent groups of rows (with duplicates)

Tags: r, indexing, grouping, addition, col

The question is similar to [(Update) Add index column to data.frame based on two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44245666/add-index-column-to-data-frame-based-on-two-columns)

Here my example data.frame:

```
df = read.table(text = 'ID  Day Count   Count_group 
77661   14498   4   5
76552   14498   4   5
37008   14498   4   5
34008   14498   4   5
30004   14497   1   5
30004   14497   1   4   
28047   14496   3   4   
28049   14496   3   4   
29003   14496   3   4   
69012   14468   1   4   
69007   14467   3   4   
69012   14467   3   4   
69020   14467   3   4   
42003   13896   2   4   
42011   13896   2   4   
22001   13895   2   4   
23007   13895   2   4   
28047   14496   3   3   
28049   14496   3   3   
29003   14496   3   3   
69007   14467   3   3   
69012   14467   3   3   
69020   14467   3   3   
48005   14271   2   2   
48007   14271   2   2   
22001   13895   2   2   
23007   13895   2   2   
47011   14320   1   2   
73005   14319   1   2   
73005   14319   1   1', header = TRUE)
```

The `Count` col shows the sum of the `ID` values grouped by `Day`.
The `Count_group` shows the sum of the unique `Count` vales grouped by `Day` and `Day -1`.

I need to create an index column which groups the `Count_group` by `Day` and `Day -1` following the descending order of the `df` (with duplicates!).

Here my expected output:

```
ID     Day  Count Count_group index_col
77661   14498   4   5           1
76552   14498   4   5           1
37008   14498   4   5           1
34008   14498   4   5           1
30004   14497   1   5           1
30004   14497   1   4           2
28047   14496   3   4           2
28049   14496   3   4           2
29003   14496   3   4           2
69012   14468   1   4           3
69007   14467   3   4           3
69012   14467   3   4           3
69020   14467   3   4           3
42003   13896   2   4           4
42011   13896   2   4           4
22001   13895   2   4           4
23007   13895   2   4           4
28047   14496   3   3           5
28049   14496   3   3           5
29003   14496   3   3           5
69007   14467   3   3           6
69012   14467   3   3           6
69020   14467   3   3           6
48005   14271   2   2           7
48007   14271   2   2           7
22001   13895   2   2           8
23007   13895   2   2           8
47011   14320   1   2           9
73005   14319   1   2           9
73005   14319   1   1          10
```

And do the same but with `index_col` grouping by 3 days: `Day`, `Day -1` and `Day -2`:

```
    df_2 = read.table(text = 'ID Day Count Count_group
30004   14497   1   5
28047   14496   3   5
28049   14496   3   5
29003   14496   3   5
69012   14495   1   5
69007   14467   3   5
69012   14467   3   5
69020   14467   3   5
42003   14466   1   5
42011   14465   1   5
28047   14496   3   4
28049   14496   3   4
29003   14496   3   4
69012   14995   1   4
22001   13895   2   4
23007   13895   2   4
28047   13894   2   4
28049   13894   2   4
42003   14466   1   2
42011   14465   1   2
28047   13894   2   2
28049   13894   2   2
69012   14995   1   1
42011   14465   1   1', header = TRUE)
```

Expected output:

```
ID     Day  Count Count_group index_col
30004   14497   1   5           1
28047   14496   3   5           1
28049   14496   3   5           1
29003   14496   3   5           1
69012   14495   1   5           1
69007   14467   3   5           2
69012   14467   3   5           2
69020   14467   3   5           2
42003   14466   1   5           2
42011   14465   1   5           2
28047   14496   3   4           3
28049   14496   3   4           3
29003   14496   3   4           3
69012   14995   1   4           3
22001   13895   2   4           4
23007   13895   2   4           4
28047   13894   2   4           4
28049   13894   2   4           4
42003   14466   1   2           5
42011   14465   1   2           5
28047   13894   2   2           6
28049   13894   2   2           6
69012   14995   1   1           7
42011   14465   1   1           8
```

Do you have any suggestion?
I desire to create a generic code that could be applied (with a few adjustments) to both df, df_2 and to other data.frames with grouping variable of n days.

Comment: I think there is a typo on the `df_2` at line 5, the value of `Day`. It should be 14495 insteed of 14995.

Comment: question updated with new df

Comment: Is it possible to have somethings like: 
`76552   14498   3   4 \n
 37008   14498   3   4 \n
 34008   14498   3   4 \n
 30004   14497   1   4 \n
 30004   14497   1   4` ? And what is the process to compute the column `Count` because it doesn't understant how it's possible to have the lines 5-6 with `Count=1`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>% mutate(index_col = cumsum(!c(+Inf,diff(Day))%in%c(0,-1)))
```

**Explanation**:

```
 c(+Inf,diff(Day))
```

As you want two consecutive days, I compute the difference on the `Day` with `diff(Day)`. As `diff` return vector of size `n-1`, I have to add a value for the top of the vector, I choose `+Inf`.

```
!(... %in% c(0,-1))
```

I test that the value is the same `Day` or `Day-1` as they must be grouped, I want when it's not the case.

```
cumsum(...)
```

Finally, I use `cumsum` to know how many of change occur.

**The output:**

It's work for your two exemples

```
> df %>% mutate(index_col = cumsum(!c(+Inf,diff(Day))%in%c(0,-1)))

      ID   Day Count Count_group index_col
1  30004 14497     1           4         1
2  28047 14496     3           4         1
3  28049 14496     3           4         1
4  29003 14496     3           4         1
5  69012 14468     1           4         2
6  69007 14467     3           4         2
7  69012 14467     3           4         2
8  69020 14467     3           4         2
9  42003 13896     2           4         3
10 42011 13896     2           4         3
11 22001 13895     2           4         3
12 23007 13895     2           4         3
13 28047 14496     3           3         4
14 28049 14496     3           3         4
15 29003 14496     3           3         4
16 69007 14467     3           3         5
17 69012 14467     3           3         5
18 69020 14467     3           3         5
19 48005 14271     2           2         6
20 48007 14271     2           2         6
21 22001 13895     2           2         7
22 23007 13895     2           2         7
23 47011 14320     1           2         8
24 73005 14319     1           2         8
25 73005 14319     1           1         8
```

and

```
> df_2 %>% mutate(index_col = cumsum(!c(+Inf,diff(Day))%in%c(0,-1)))

      ID   Day Count Count_group index_col
1  30004 14497     1           5         1
2  28047 14496     3           5         1
3  28049 14496     3           5         1
4  29003 14496     3           5         1
5  69012 14495     1           5         1
6  69007 14467     3           5         2
7  69012 14467     3           5         2
8  69020 14467     3           5         2
9  42003 14466     1           5         2
10 42011 14465     1           5         2
11 28047 14496     3           4         3
12 28049 14496     3           4         3
13 29003 14496     3           4         3
14 69012 14495     1           4         3
15 22001 13895     2           4         4
16 23007 13895     2           4         4
17 28047 13894     2           4         4
18 28049 13894     2           4         4
19 42003 14466     1           2         5
20 42011 14465     1           2         5
21 28047 13894     2           2         6
22 28049 13894     2           2         6
23 69012 14995     1           1         7
24 42011 14465     1           1         8
```